# Copying rows from an Excel sheet to one in a different Excel file based on criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to start by telling you that I spent at least 2 hours reading different questions/answers on Stackoverflow and random google search results. I couldn't find an answer to my specific problem although a lot of questions/answers dealt with similar problems.

Every week, I'm manually copying rows from an Excel sheet into another Excel sheet based on certain criteria. In one column, the value of the cells that interest me are "not done" and in a second column I'm looking for due date that is in the past, i.e. overdue items. If both criteria are met, I copy the entire row into a newly created sheet in another Excel file.

I know VBA basics and thought about making my life easier by writing a macro that copies the respective rows into another Excel file and a new sheet. However, I'm not able to write a rather complex macro yet :(

Can you please help me by explaining how to write two loops (of some sort) that first look through the first column (find cells where value is not X) and after that look for a date in the past in a second column and then copy the rows where these two criteria met? Is that even possible with VBA? I'm not asking for the whole macro because I like to figure out how to get the remaining code right, but these loops are very complicated for a beginner and I'd really appreciate some guidance here.

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read this wall of text.

Edit: After checking excel-easy (thanks @maxhob17 ) I managed to make some progress. Please see this code so you get an idea of my progress. This code gets all the relevant rows based on the first criterion (status = done) and copies them into a new sheet in the same Excel file.

```
Public Sub Copy_Relevant_Items()
Dim CurrentWorkbook As Workbook
Dim InputWS As Worksheet
Dim OutputWS As Worksheet

Set CurrentWorkbook = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)
Set InputWS = CurrentWorkbook.Sheets("Overview")
Set OutputWS = CurrentWorkbook.Sheets("Relevant")

Dim criterion As String
criterion = "Done"
Dim cells As range, cell As range


'Find the last used row in a Column: column C in this example
With InputWS
  LastRow = .cells(.rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row
End With

Set cells = range("C2:C" & LastRow)

'Copy all the relevant rows into another sheet
For Each cell In cells
    If cell.Value <> criterion Then

        cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=OutputWS.range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    End If
Next cell
```

End Sub

Comment: i can suggest you to use Power Query (if your Excel is over 2010 version)  , very easy to use for beginners. Just make a excel connection, filter for your criteria however you need, and no need to copy/paste,  just right-click "Update" and you'r done... [see photo](http://imgur.com/a/qM88G)

Comment: Hi, brief outline: you will want to start by defining a [Range](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/range-object.html) to represent the data you want to check. You can then use a [For Loop](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html) to go through each row. You can then check both of your conditions for column 1 and 2 using an [IF](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/if-then-statement.html) statement with [logical operators](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/logical-operators.html). Then when the IF is True you can copy that row somewhere else

Comment: Thank you maxhob17, I will check out excel-easy now :)

Comment: please explain what _" look for a date in the past in a second column "_ actually should mean.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for not explaining it properly. Imagine a column showing due dates. I want to look for due dates that are in the past, i.e. items that are overdue in combination with criterion #1. I will edit my question to make it clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use `AutoFilter()`

assuming your database spans from column A to D and dates are in column D then you could code

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Copy_Relevant_Items()
    Dim InputWS As Worksheet, OutputWS As Worksheet
    Dim criterion As String

    Set InputWS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Overview")
    Set OutputWS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Relevant")
    criterion = "Done"

    With InputWS
        With .Range("A1:D" & .cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) '<--| reference its columns A to C from row 1 down to column A last not empty row. Change A and D to your actual data limit columns index
            MsgBox .Address
            .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>" & criterion '<--| filter column C cells with content different from 'Criterion'. change "3" to your actual relative position of "status" column inside your database
            .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="<" & CLng(Date)   '<--| filter column D cells with content less than current date. change "4" to your actual relative position of "date" column inside your database
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=OutputWS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1) '<--| if any cell filtered other than headers then copy them to 'OutputWS'
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I will search for a tutorial on how to use AutoFilter()  properly :)

Comment: You are welcome. BTW if you're adopting this solution you may want to mark answer as accepted ;-)

Comment: Yes, I will do that now! Sorry.

Comment: @BennyC, ok. you just have to _"click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in"_

Comment: Thanks, I found it .:)

Comment: Check this out:  https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win006.htm